# Wordcount example error

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, word-count

Does anyone know how to solve this error? 
I have read that I can edit in the `fileutils.setPermission` and remove lines with `checkReturnValue`, but I don't know how.

```
13/03/10 13:04:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/03/10 13:04:14 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:Nesreen.Mamdouh cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-Nesreen.Mamdouh\mapred\staging\Nesreen.Mamdouh64097525\.staging to 0700
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-Nesreen.Mamdouh\mapred\staging\Nesreen.Mamdouh64097525\.staging to 0700
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:689)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:662)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:189)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:856)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
at BigDataPackage.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:55)
```

Comment: Can you provide us with more background information? What line is causing this error? What are the current permissions on `\tmp\hadoop-Nesreen.Mamdouh\mapred\staging\Nesreen.Mamdouh64097525\.staging`? Which user executes the program?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running this program on Windows.  I believe there is a similar problem solved [here](https://github.com/congainc/patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win)

Check some information on Windows-hadoop installation [here](http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html)

Comment: and the part of code that gets this error is: JobClient.runJob(conf); its hadoop stable version 1.0.4and the permissions of \tmp\hadoop-Nesreen.Mamdouh\mapred\staging\Nesreen.Mamdouh64097525\.staging is set to be used by everyone with full access, and im running eclipse as an administrator,

Also I haven't installed Cygwin.

Comment: and im running it on windows

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below workaround to suppress this error:

1. Under your hadoop directory go to src->core->org->apache->hadoop->fs
2. Open FileUtil.Java
3. Comment out the code inside checkReturnValue function at line 685.
4. Re create hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar and include it in the build path of your eclipse project.

This should solve the problem.

Comment: I can get the below step, can you please elaborate.

Re create hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar and include it in the build path of your eclipse project.